Redirect SSMTP emails from a computer to another email server
I was following this article on setting up a Mail Relay from one server to another, as I want to redirect all the system email, such as crontab errors from Server1 to Server2.
In order to do this, I have edited my SSMTP config file as following:
/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
mailhub=<server2_ip>:587
rewriteDomain=codrutsoft.com

FromLineOverride=YES
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES

AuthUser=codrut@codrutsoft.com
AuthPass=<my_password>

Where I entered the correct password and IP.
I have set up a cron job to echo an "error" every minute, for this to be sent to the email server.
To see cron logs for output email, I use the following command:
journalctl -u cron _TRANSPORT=stdout

This seems to be an issue with the server not accepting the email, as you can see from the following log:
sendmail: RCPT TO:<codrut@codrutsoft.com> (553 5.7.1 <root@codrutsoft.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user codrut@codrutsoft.com)

Which I assume Is caused by the fact that the email is sent from root and not from my username, codrut. I'm pretty new to email hosting and I don't really understand the issue.
And also, including my password in the ssmtp.conf seems like really bad practice, even for an non-primary account. So I was wondering If I could just forward the email directly as If It were sent from Server1, and that would not require a password. I think It should be possible.
I'd be grateful for all the help!

In the end, I just created an root@codrutsoft.com which I just set to send the email forward to codrut@codrutsoft.com .
And having the password for this account exposed in 'ssmtp.conf' is not as big a security issue as I believed. That's because the file needs sudo access to be read, and If an malicious actor had access to root, I would have bigger problems than an exposed system mail account.
In rest, everything works as expected.
